# Why are fputc and fputs outputs not immediately noticable?

Tags: c

I am writing a C program, but not seeing the results of either an `fputc` or `fputs` call. I need help with understanding why that is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  FILE *stream;
  int file_state;
  int input1=0;
  stream = fopen("data3.txt", "w");
  if (stream == NULL)
    puts("file open error");   
  puts("input data");
  while (input1 != EOF)
    {
      input1=fgetc(stdin);
      putchar(input1);
      //fputc(input1, stdout);
      //fprintf(stream, "tee");
      //fputc('A', stream);
      //fputs("sass", stream);
    }
  file_state=fclose(stream);
  if(file_state==EOF)
    puts("file close error");
  return 0;
}
```

Problem is that `fputc` and `fputs` do not work properly.
I am on mac lion 64 bit, and using `make` and `./file_name` on the terminal.

In the while loop, if I write

```
putchar(input1);
```

it outputs (prints) to the terminal.
However, all of the commented lines don't work.

```
fputc(input1, stdout);
```

also prints a blank line on the terminal.

The program creates a file, yet seems to be completely empty. What could be the problem?

Comment: you should check the return values from your output-functions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking at the contents of the file while it is still openend? Note the file writes are buffered, so you may not be able to see the data until the stream is closed/flushed.

If that is the case you can try calling `fflush(stream)` as the last line in the loop. Or wait until the file is closed, of course.

Also note that if you end your program with Ctrl-C the data may never be written at all!

The difference with `stdout` is that this stream is usually *line buffered*, meaning that the stream is automatically flushed whenever you output a new line character, but ordinary streams are not.

Comment: Thank You so much! that was a lot of help!

Comment: @SML - You are welcome! But remember that if you find the answer satisfactory you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have problems because some strings aren't null terminated with '\0'.

```
stream = fopen("data3.txt\0", "w\0");
if (stream == NULL)
  puts("file open error\0");   
puts("input data\0");
while (input1 != EOF)
  {
    input1=fgetc(stdin);
    putchar(input1);
    //fputc(input1, stdout);
    //fprintf(stream, "tee\0");
    //fputc('A', stream);
    //fputs("sass\0", stream);
  }
file_state=fclose(stream);
if(file_state==EOF)
  puts("file close error\0");
return 0;
```

Comment: String literals are always null terminated.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. You need to use the full path of the file. Go to Finder and take the file's pathname by pressing option key after double-clicking the file. Then it should work.

Let me know if that was the problem.